# How to verify one file of a package, not the RPM itself

Tags: linux, security, rpm, checksum

For instance, can I somehow use `rpm` to verify that `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` is unchanged since it was installed on the system?  I know I can do this with an entire RPM, but I want to know if I can do this on individual files or config files using the builtin `rpm` checksumming capabilities or something similar.  Red Hat Linux 5/6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
rpm -Vf /etc/pam.d/system-auth
```

although in this example, `rpm` will complain that the file isn't owned by any package as it's a symlink.  In this instance you need to make sure that you are running the command against that actual file, not the symlink to it:

```
rpm -Vf /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac
```

Comment: Not if you put a trailing slash I think, which causes it to dereference the symlink.  At least it worked for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know that this was asked/answered a long time ago, but I don't think that this is correct (maybe behaviour changed in `rpm`, but I don't think so).

`rpm -Vf ${FILE}` seems to use the specified file to identify the package, (like `rpm -qf` does) but then verifies the whole package, which is what `rpm -V` always does.

To only get the details for a single file, I think the easiest solution is:

```
rpm -vf ${FILE} | grep ${FILE}
```

If you want a status to represent "has this file been modified since installation", you could do something like:

```
FILE=/etc/pam.d/system-auth
if rpm -vf ${FILE} | grep -q ${FILE}
then
    echo "${FILE} has been modified"
fi
```